# Testing private methods using RhinoMocks

Tags: c#, tdd, rhino-mocks

I work in TDD environment and basically I am facing with a dilemma which I  think is very important in TDD environment. As a programmer, you want your methods to be as readable as possible. To achieve that, we tend to partition our methods in multiple private methods as well. While doing that all that code which was moved to the private function looses it's test ability.

Rhino test class cannot see all those private methods and I need to be able to run tests against those methods as well. I do not want them to be public because it does not make sense to keep them public.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you working in Visual Studio?  Create a Private Accessor; this generates a proxy class that exposes the private methods.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Private Accessors are [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh507838.aspx) in VS 2012.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I qoute a part of your question:

> [...] we tend to partition our methods in multiple private methods [...]

This is wrong. If you follow a [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and good OOP design, your methods would be much independent and simpler. If you feel like you want to extract a yet another *private* method to make your *public* one look shorter, give it a thought first. Maybe, you can refactor it in a separate class?

You do not test *private* methods, because you test *public* contracts and not the details of implementations. If you want to have something distantly similar to *private* methods testing, make them *internal* and set [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

Another method (pointed by R. Harvey) is to write a wrapper class that wraps you *private* methods into *public* ones. This approach has a benefit that you don't need to make your *private* methods *internal*. The downside is that for every *private* method you will have a wrapper *public* method. So the amount of methods may double.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. They were useful.

Comment: But I have something to say here. Basically I always make sure that the method that I am definig is single responsibility. But for example, I have a public method that is two steps and 1. Generate a random number and 2. put it in a list if it already does not exist. Well, I think its good practice to put both steps in two private methods an then  call them by parent public method. The problem here is that if I put them in a wrapper class then it is basically test driven design rather than design driven test.

Comment: @Californicated I agree with you that there are places when you just use private methods. But if this starts to be a problem, like when you have too many of them. And you feel like there is a need to unit-test them, I would first try an easy `InternalsVisibleTo`, then I will try to refactor (see [chain of responsibilities](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx) or [strategy](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx) patterns for your sample) and lastly I will try to wrap methods (there possibly can be a simple generic wrapper based on `Func<T,...,T>`)

Comment: Excellent!! I think we are on the same page with this. I think the one which is least invasive here is InternalsVisisbleTo. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by others, one way to test non-public methods is to make them internal and use `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. However, I would strongly suggest against that.

Private methods should be covered by unit tests by testing public methods that use them. Of course, as time progresses and you add more functionality to the class under test, it gets more and more complicated to setup your tests. This is a good indicator that the class has too much responsibility and you should split it into multiple smaller classes. You can then make these smaller classes a *dependency* of original class and mock them in your tests - that will simplify the tests again.

While doing that, you don't have to entirely relinquish private methods - it's a good idea to use them to make your code more readable without using comments.