# Reflection for unit testing internal properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I have a public class(`TargetContainerDto`) that has 2 internal properties. An enum and a type that contains a value from that enum.

I'm trying to unit test the type, but I'm having problems.

```
internal enum TargetContainerType
{
    Endpoint,
    Group,
    User,
    UserGroup
}


internal TargetContainerType Type { get; set; }
```

This is my reflection code in my test class

```
public void setType(TargetContainerDto t, int val)
{
    BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    PropertyInfo pi = t.GetType().GetProperty("Type", bf);
    pi.SetValue(t, val, null);
}

public TargetContainerDto setTypeTo(TargetContainerDto t, int val)
{
    setType(t, val);
    return t;
}
```

`TargetContainerDto` has more properties than Type, but they are public so testing them is fine. The `iconURL` is a string defined in `TargetContainerDto` depending on what the type is. Here is my Testmethod:

```
public void DefaultSubGroupIcon()
{
    var o1 = new TargetContainerDto
    {
        Id = 1234,
        DistinguishedName = "1.1.1.1",
        SubGroup = "test",
    };
    setType(o1, 3);
    Assert.AreEqual(o1.IconUrl, "/App_Themes/Common/AppControl/Images/workstation1.png");
}
```

I call setTypeTo in test method when I need to set the typevalue, but I'm getting a `MethodAccessException`. I think it's because I don't have access to the enum. How can I access the enum through reflection?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious - have you ever considered stop using reflexion in tests to access internal state of objects under tests and redesign your application a bit?

Comment: Can you post the Exception? Does Type have a value set before or is it null?

Comment: By the way, I've just tested your scenario and it worked well. Could you please provide more details, not only exception details, but  your **TargetContainerDto** class definition? What is the base class for it?

Comment: You should not be using a variable named Type as it is [already taken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with other comments that you should try to redesign to avoid testing internal state, however I did try your code and it works fine for me (.Net 4 on VS2012).

My class library under test looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    internal enum TargetContainerType
    {
        Endpoint,
        Group,
        User,
        UserGroup
    }

    public class TargetContainerDto
    {
        internal TargetContainerType Type
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Type);
        }
    }
}
```

And the test program (a Console app) looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using ClassLibrary;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TargetContainerDto();
            setType(test, 1);
            test.Print();
        }

        public static void setType(TargetContainerDto t, int val)
        {
            BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            PropertyInfo pi = t.GetType().GetProperty("Type", bf);
            pi.SetValue(t, val, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out `Group`, as expected. If we can identify the differences between this and your actual code, we may be able to find the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. the only difference i can see is that you have the internal enum declared outside of the TargetContainerDto class. Also my test app is a unit test but still should behave similar.

Comment: it worked for me when i got rid of the setTypeTo method . Thanks very much. Il mark you as answer as youre the only one who responded in realtion to reflection and not alternative wys. thanks

Answer (score 11):

Mark your assembly with the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute and you don't need to use reflection in your test dll.

e.g. in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in your application dll add the following line:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Be aware that doing this will prevent Code Analysis from detecting unused internals.

Answer (score 6):

You asking the wrong question. A better question would be:

> > How do I stop testing internal state of the class?

But, if you utterly need this, there are couple of ways described in this relevant [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11401920/706456)